# int returns garbage value

Tags: c++, netbeans, int, mingw, average

I have a problem: my int returns too big of a value when my program is executed.
This program counts the arithmetic average.

For example: When I typing 1,2,3,4,5, it says *2293393*.

```
/* 
 * File:   main.cpp
 * Author: Natch
 *
 * Created on 4 listopad 2012, 15:32
 */

#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

/*
 * 
 */
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int n,x;
    x = 0;
    /*
     * a - array
     * x - repeat
     * n - array fields
     * suma - array fields sum
     */
    cout << "Srednia liczb" << endl;
    cout << "Program oblicza srednia z x liczb." << endl;
    cout << "Podaj ilosc liczb do obliczenia sredniej:" << endl;
    cin >> n;
    int a[n];

    while(x<n) {
        x++;
        cout << "Podaj " << x << " liczbe:" << endl;
        cin >> a[x];
    }
    long int suma;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        suma += a[i];
    }

    int srednia = suma/n;
    cout << "Srednia wynosi:" << endl << srednia << endl;
    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Sorry for my English, I'm from Poland.

You can translate couts in google translate(pl->en).

Comment: Please turn on your compiler's warnings.

Comment: Compiler haven't any warnings.

Comment: Oh. You need to turn on optimizations too to get it. (`-O1 -Wall` is enough.) (And add `-std=c++0x -pendatic` while you're at it, so that you know you're using a GCC extension.)

Answer (score 4):

Your program has a classic "off by one" error: you increment `x` before using it as an index in `a[x]`, so the zeroth element remains uninitialized:

```
while(x<n) {
    cout << "Podaj " << (x+1) << " liczbe:" << endl;
    cin >> a[x++];
}
```

Comment: @user1798217 You are welcome! You may want to accept the answer by clicking the grey checkmark outline to indicate that you are no longer looking for an improved answer, and to earn a brand-new badge on stack overflow.

Answer (score 2):

Initialize the variable suma to zero.

```
long int suma=0;
```

Instead of incrementing `x` before `cout`, increment it in the `cout`.

```
cout << "Podaj " << x++ << " liczbe:" << endl;
```